# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07000e for fragment TestFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

This is my code:

```
View popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new TabAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());

            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.pager);               
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            indicator.setViewPager(pager);

 class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {
        public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return TestFragment.newInstance(position, MainActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconResId(int index) {
            return CONTENT[index];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }
    }
```

xml files

main.xml - Used linear layout

popup.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     
    android:orientation="vertical" >


  <com.test.TabPageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Testfragment.java

```
public final class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";   
    KeyClickListener mListener;

    public static TestFragment newInstance(int content, KeyClickListener listener) {
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        fragment.mContent = content;
        fragment.mListener = listener;
        return fragment;
    }

    private int mContent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        if ((savedInstanceState != null)
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
            mContent = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_CONTENT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater ll = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View v = ll.inflate(R.layout.activty_grids, null);      
        GridView gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), Constant.ITEMS, mListener, mContent);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
    }
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/footer" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_for_key"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/keyboard_height"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout
```

>

Comment: once clean your project and try.

Comment: can you post xml layout and java code of TestFragment

Comment: added main xml layout and java codes.

Comment: error may be in R.layout.activty_grids and onCreateView() of Fragment

Comment: I don't think. this is error log:  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1012)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:523)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:476)
  at com.test.TabPageIndicator.setCurrentItem(TabPageIndicator.java:246)

Comment: @Kedi did you resolve it ? if yes please let me know what should i do?

Comment: No, But I changed my code. And used as a different way.